# Generating table, giving rows IDs

Tags: javascript, html, auto-generate

I'm generating table cells using JavaScript and I'd like to assign incremental IDs to the the generated cells. I tried with the HTML Tag for `<td id="">` but, sadly, it didn't work out.

My code to generate the table cells is show below. How can I assign incremental IDs to the cells?

```js
function tab_add() {
    i = 1;
    var output = localStorage.getItem('x');     

    var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    var row = table.insertRow(0);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    cell1.innerHTML = output;
    cell2.innerHTML = i;
    i = i+1;                    
}
```

Comment: this is an html/javaSCRIPT question, not java.  I have updated your tags accordingly

Comment: Ah, sorry! My bad, first time here ^^ And shows just how much I still have to learn >< Thanks fopr changing it for me.

Comment: apparently someone has to peer review that for it to go live.  whatever.  anyway, regarding your question: are you trying to fill the CONTENT of the cell, or give the cell itself an id?

Also, with the code you have there, the value of "i" is always 1, cause you reset it every time the function is called.

Comment: Are you generating the table all at once, or are you adding rows dynamically on user input? I'd like to see more code, where this function is being called. There is likely a better way to structure it.

Comment: Your solution for dynamically creating tables forces the browser to recalculate everything each time you do an insert() or an innerHTML. Using a DocumentFragment and then adding that once to the DOM saves a lot of resources (depending on table's size ofcourse)

Answer (score 1):

You may just do something like `cell1.id = i;` or `row.id = i;`

Comment: For reference: [Element.id](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/id)

Comment: Thank you very much! Seems like a case of tree and forests ^^" Sorry to ask for something that easy. Will implement that asap and report back.